# Rearranging Differential Equation

Tags: differential

I'm completely new to differential equations. I'm just doing random problems online about them. One simple problem asks to re-arrange the following so that the x's and y's are all on one side:

$x^2+dy/dx +xy=1   $

Can I just use algebra to do it? Like:

$dy/dx= x^2/xy  $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation $$x^2+dy/dx +xy=1$$ is not separable so you can not rearrange it so all $x$ terms are on one side and and all $y$ terms go on the other side.

The equation is linear and we can solve it easily by multiplying both sides by integrating factor.

$$dy/dx +xy=1-x^2$$ where integrating factor is $e^{x^2/2}$

$$\frac {d}{dx} (ye^{x^2/2})=(1-x^2) e^{x^2/2}$$
Which is solved by integrating both sides.